# java Main Thread manage launching other Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, fifo, java.util.concurrent

I would describe my problem:

- I am developing application for document generation (Office documents) on asynchronous mode so I use Threads
- due to performance constraints, I must launch only 2 threads at the same time,
- To not block user to launch document generation while two threads are running, I thought to develop a main thread containing ArrayDeque object as a thread stack, where user can add creation request (as an object implementing Collable or Runnable interface) and use Concurrent API to launch Threads on FIFO Mode

  The questions are:
- how can ensure running the main Thread as a singleton for all user ?
- How can I call ArrayDeque on Main Running Thread

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like a simple case of using an `ExecutorService` with a pool of two threads:

```
class Task implements Runnable {
    ...
}

ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
exec.submit(new Task()); // submit task to the queue for asynchronous processing
```

The `ExecutorService` will encapsulate a pool of threads and a work queue. Thread will automatically pick up new work as they finish previous tasks.

Comment: Thanks Tudor,In fact the ExecutorService will not submit the new task unless The Two first Added Tasks are finished to not crush the JVM

Comment: Technically there will be 3 (user) threads this way but the main thread will finish working as soon as all the tasks are submitted.

Comment: @Karbala The Task is submitted to the queue immediately, but won't be processed until one of the worker threads is free.

Comment: @Mark: OK and this will not lock other user when launching the process? I mean when he click to generate the document there will not have a waiting process till other threads are finished? the idea is to not lock user HMI, I hope you understand me , Thanks

Comment: @Karbala: No, adding tasks to the queue will not block the posting thread (main thread), even if there still are pending jobs already.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this make a solution

Comment: @Karbala The tasks are added to an unbounded queue, so the thread issuing new tasks does not have to wait for older tasks to finish.

Comment: @Patricia: this is exactly what I need, The newest Threads wait for previous Threads to finish, thus why I wanted to use a unique ArrayDeque<? extends Callable> for all users